# Tracing back method call of overridden method in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex

I am looking at a source code and it has a method  named updateDisplayList. There are various methods in this source code with similar name. However I am interested in one particular updateDisplayList method. I want to check where this method is getting called. I have tried using CTRL+SHIFT+G in eclipse which returns me all the references of this method in that source code. However as there are many methods with same name, those references are also getting returned. How can I know where that particular updateDisplayList method is getting called?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry for vague explanation of problem. I have updated the problem statement. Please check.

Comment: Per `updateDateList()`, as a `protected` function, it is only accessible to that class or subclasses that extend that class.

Comment: While the method is protected, it is essentially triggered by the Flex LayoutManager, which is responsible for "driving" the Flex component life cycle. The `updateDisplayList()` method exists in practically every Flex component. It's called very frequently. If you explain why you're interested in knowing who's calling it, perhaps we can help you get the *real* problem you seem to be investigating. You can always set a break point in this method to see who's calling it, but it gets called so often that it may not be that fruitful.

Comment: @SunilD. I think I will tell the main problem I am facing. I have two different components. If I change updateDisplayList method (i.e. add some code which does some graphical changes to the component), it is getting reflected in both components. I want it to get changed just for the component which is currently selected.

Comment: Are you asking for trace(), Alert.show(), breakpoints, 'show redraw regions' option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments `updateDisplayList()` is a Flex component life cycle method. Practically every Flex component implements this method.

If you've modified this method in one class, lets call it `ClassA`, and you're also seeing the effects of this modification in other classes, it must mean that the other classes inherit from `ClassA` in some way.

To determine who's inheriting from `ClassA`, you can just search for that class name in your project. This will likely find the other class that you're looking for. However, there could be a series of classes that inherit from `ClassA` so you might have to look deeper than that (find all the classes that extend `ClassA` and then search for those classes).  This might be a slippery slope and may not be fruitful.

Another approach is to set a breakpoint in the `updateDisplayList()` method in `ClassA`. As I mentioned, you'll hit this breakpoint frequently. In FlashBuilder/Eclipse, you can use the "expressions" window and inspect the value of `this`. If `this` is `ClassA`, it's not the droid(s) you're looking for, so let execution resume.

I'm sure there are a handful of other ways to get to the bottom of this. But `updateDisplayList()` is such a common method, there's no point in searching for that method name :)